# PHP: how to add double quote to a PHP variable

Tags: php

When i echo "$time"; - The output is 2015-07-27 18:17:47
But i need to output as "2015-07-27 18:17:47".

I have been trying various string concatenations such as : echo "."$time"."; But couldn't get the desired output? What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this concatenation

```
echo '"' . $time . '"';
```

or use `printf()` like so

```
printf('"%s"', $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just escape them:

`echo "\"$time\"";`

You could also use single around the double quotes:

`echo '"' . $time . '"';`

See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for more info on escape sequences when using double quotes.